# How to fix "global name --- is not defined error "

Tags: python

I created two classes, one for a node object and the other for a BST (binary search tree object). For the binary search tree, I have implemented two methods, one for inserting a given value (new_val) into the correct position in the tree and the other for searching the BST for a node with the given value. To implement these functions, I have created helper functions (i.e. insertRecursive and searchRecursive), which work recursively to attain the function goals. For some reason, when I run the code, I am getting the error "NameError: global name 'insert_Recursive' is not defined" and I am unsure why. Any advice on how to solve the issue would be much appreciated.

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

class BST(object):
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = Node(root)

def insert(self, new_val):
    self.insert_Recursive(self.root, new_val)

def insert_Recursive(self, start, new_val):
    if start != None:
        if (new_val > start.value):
            insert_Recursive(start.right, new_val)
        else:
            insert_Recursive(start.left, new_val)
    else:
        start.value = new_val


def search(self, find_val):
    return searchRecursive(self.root, find_val)

def searchRecursive(self, start, find_val):
    if start != None:
        if (find_val == start.value):
            return True
        elif(find_val > start.value):
            searchRecursive(start.right, find_val)
        else:
            searchRecursive(start.left, find_val)
    else:
        return False

tree = BST(4)
tree.insert(2)
tree.insert(1)
tree.insert(3)
tree.insert(5)
print tree.search(4)
print tree.search(6)
```

Comment: Everything from `insert` down to `searchRecursive` needs to be indented to be part of `BST`.

Comment: I don't know why but on my online code editor its formatted correctly with the right indentations, but when I transferred it into stack overflow, the indentations got messed. Thanks for the response though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 if (new_val > start.value):
            insert_Recursive(start.right, new_val)
```

Should be

```
if (new_val > start.value):
            self.insert_Recursive(start.right, new_val)
```